# Rendering results in weird white markings on image

Tags: rendering

When rendering I get this weird result with white markings on it.
On the viewport on rendered preview the image looks ok.

I am pretty new to this, so just trying to learn the basics.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Rendering issue]

[image: How it should look like]

Answer (score 4):

You probably have an object hidden in your viewport but visible in your render...

Mark it to not be visible in the render to get rid of this:

[image]